# getting mime type error with nginx and nextjs

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have the following nginx config file:

```
# Cache zone
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=STATIC:10m inactive=7d use_temp_path=off;

upstream nextjs_sales {
  server nextjs_sales:3000;
}

upstream nextjs_rents {
  server nextjs_rents:3000;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;

  server_name _;

  types {
    application/javascript js;
    text/css css;
    application/json json;
    image/svg+xml svg;
  }

  server_tokens off;

  gzip on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_comp_level 4;
  gzip_types text/css application/javascript image/svg+xml;

  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

  # SALES APP
  location /comprar {
    proxy_pass http://nextjs_sales;
  }

  # SALES APP BUILT ASSETS (E.G. JS BUNDLES)
  location /comprar/_next/static {
    proxy_cache STATIC;
    proxy_pass http://nextjs_sales;
  }

  # SALES APP STATIC ASSETS (E.G. IMAGES)
  location /comprar/static {
    proxy_cache STATIC;
    proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
    proxy_cache_valid 60m;
    proxy_pass http://nextjs_sales;
  }

  # RENTS APP
  location /alquilar {
    proxy_pass http://nextjs_rents;
  }

  # RENTS APP BUILT ASSETS (E.G. JS BUNDLES)
  location /alquilar/_next/static {
    proxy_cache STATIC;
    proxy_pass http://nextjs_rents;
  }

  # RENTS APP STATIC ASSETS (E.G. IMAGES)
  location /alquilar/static {
    proxy_cache STATIC;
    proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
    proxy_cache_valid 60m;
    proxy_pass http://nextjs_rents;
  }

  location / {
    stub_status on;
    access_log   off;
  }
}
```

but even though I have the `types` property I'm getting:

[image]

Any suggestion or help to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The upstream servers (`http://nextjs_*`) may be setting the incorrect content-type headers in their responses, which can be mitigated with [`proxy_hide_header`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_hide_header). Multiple content-type response headers can be identified with `curl -I` against URLs on the proxy or upstream servers:

```bash
$ curl -I localhost/.../file.js          # Proxy
$ curl -I nextjs_sales:3000/.../file.js  # Upstream
```